# Collaborative spreadsheet application

Tags: macos, ios, software-recommendation, numbers

I'm looking for an application that will allow me to create fields that represent 'points' to keep tally on mod actions by my online community. Another mod or user who i give permissions to can update the points while mods without permissions to update the points have read only access.
Once points are updated, the 'total' column is updated.
While you get 1 point for every mod action, some column should be worth more or have a higher multiplier than others.
I'm not even sure if a spreadsheet is strictly needed or if it can be something else.
I've tried google sheets but that seems clunky.
I was wondering if there was a mac specific or ios specific app i could use that wouldn't require the participants of the spreadsheet to have a mac to view it.
maybe something with bot an ios and android app.
[image]

Comment: You ask for an cross-platform app recommendation, which isn't the best fit on this site—perhaps [SoftwareRecommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)? Back to spreadsheets, it does sound like a spreadsheet is the answer, so any collaborative, cross-platform spreadsheet app sounds fitting. What was clunky about Sheets? Have you tried [Numbers collaboration](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206181)? (note: no Android editing!)

Comment: Software recommendations are explicitly on topic here since one of the use cases is on Apple products. Here there are two products listed, so there’s no need to migrate this or close it due to scope. If anyone wants to discuss close reasons or scope - let’s take that to [meta] in general or in specific to this post.

Comment: I did an internet search for collaborative spreadsheet and a **LOT** of results came up. You may want to try that.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Numbers spreadsheet with the appropriate function logic, then lock the cells that viewers shouldn't touch.

Then share a link from Numbers, with no protection so that anyone can use the web link.

I think you'll be pretty pleased with it.

Comment: No, I'm not going to code the spreadsheet for you. It's pretty easy. You should be able to do it in an evening.